# After I have my workspace set up, how do I integrate a package or install one that another user has created?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS but I am trying to install a package that has already been created. I'm just not sure where do I find these packages or how to install them. Or can someone tell me where in the tutorial does it state how to integrate a package. I saw how to create one but haven't run into the part where they show you how to install or locate a package. Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264619/after-i-have-my-workspace-set-up,-how-do-i-integrate-a-package-or-install-one-that-another-user-has-created?/) by [xiswitchx](https://answers.ros.org/users/30886/xiswitchx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See if #q208963, #q252478 or #q240235 clarify things.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0